# Report table with two axis/columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to know how to do this the elegant panda-way. I played arround with `pivot_table()` but I am not sure if this is the right tool for my *simple* task.

This MWE...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pandas as pd

data = {'YEAR': [2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002],
        'val': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C']}
        
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.YEAR = df.YEAR.astype('int16')
df.val = df.val.astype('category')

print(df)
```

...produce this data:

```
   YEAR val
0  2000   A
1  2000   B
2  2001   A
3  2001   A
4  2002   B
5  2002   C
```

What I want to see is something like this

```
      val
      A  B  C  Total
YEAR
2000  1  1  0  2
2001  2  0  0  2
2002  0  1  1  2
Total 3  2  1  6
```

Or the columns and rows can switch. This does not matter for me.

Or "stack" them like this

```
A                     B                    C                Total
2000 2001 2002 Total  2000 2001 2002 Total 2000 2001 2002 Total 2000 2001 2002 Total
```

I know I could to some calculations myself and add some new rows/cols to it. But I hope there is a easier way - maybe with pivot.

*EDIT*: I think one important point for me on this MWE is that `val` is categorical type and I want to have all expressions/characteristics (what is the correct word here?) shown in the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with margins:

```
new_df = pd.crosstab(df['YEAR'], df['val'], margins=True, margins_name='Total')
```

`new_df`:

```
val    A  B  C  Total
YEAR                 
2000   1  1  0      2
2001   2  0  0      2
2002   0  1  1      2
Total  3  2  1      6
```

---

For the second part about categorical types. A [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) can be used to add in any missing categories (Here adding hypothetical `D` which doesn't appear in dataset but is a category)

Setting up categories with [CategoricalDtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html#categoricaldtype)

```
cat_type = pd.CategoricalDtype(categories=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
df['val'] = df['val'].astype(cat_type)
```

`crosstab` and `reindex` based on [`Series.cat.categories`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cat.categories.html):

```
new_df = pd.crosstab(df['YEAR'], df['val'], margins=True, margins_name='Total')
new_df = new_df.reindex(columns=[*df['val'].cat.categories, 'Total'],
                        fill_value=0)
```

Or simply `reindex` from a list of values without setting up the CategoricalDtype:

```
new_df = pd.crosstab(df['YEAR'], df['val'], margins=True, margins_name='Total')
new_df = new_df.reindex(columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'Total'],
                        fill_value=0)
```

`new_df`:

```
val    A  B  C  D  Total
YEAR                    
2000   1  1  0  0      2
2001   2  0  0  0      2
2002   0  1  1  0      2
Total  3  2  1  0      6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your categorial values with [`get_dummies()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) like this:

```
pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['val']).groupby('YEAR').sum()
```

Output:

```
      val_A  val_B  val_C
YEAR                     
2000      1      1      0
2001      2      0      0
2002      0      1      1
```